# Using `If` condition to replace columns of a matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement, conditional

I have two matrices:

`tableone = {{1, "M", "0"}, {2, "M", 0}, {3, "F", 0}, {4, "M", 0}, {5, 
   "F", 0}, {6, "M", 0}, {7, "F", 0}, {8, "F", 0}, {9, "M", 0}, {10, 
   "F", 0}}`

and

`tabletwo = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {1, 20}, {4, 30}, {1, 30}, {5, 10}, {2, 
   10}, {3, 10}, {1, 50}}`

If the expected value of the third column of table 2 is greater than 20, change all values 0 in the third column in tableone to the value 1.

Indeed,

`totalcolumnsum = Sum[tabletwo[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 9}]`

I've tried

`Meantransaction = N[totalcolumnsum/Dimensions[tabletwo][[1]]]`

`If[Meantransaction > 20, 
 ReplacePart[tableone[[;; , 3]] -> 1, tableone]]` is greater than 20.

which I believe is incomplete and possibly in the wrong direction.

Can someone provide some help?

Comment: What is `Meantransaction`? I suggest that you name MMA variables in lowercase...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I'll be more careful in the future.
I've edited the OP.
Meantransaction is the expected value of the second column in tabletwo.

Comment: @Physkid tabletwo does not have a third column ,futhermore tabletwo and tableone have not the same length

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
ReplacePart[tableone, {#, 3} -> 1 & /@ 
Flatten@Position[tabletwo, {x_, y_} /; y > N@(Total[tabletwo][[2]]/Dimensions[tabletwo][[1]])]]

(*  
  {{1, "M", 0}, 
   {2, "M", 0}, 
   {3, "F", 0}, 
   {4, "M", 1}, 
   {5, "F", 1},
   {6, "M", 0},  
   {7, "F", 0}, 
   {8, "F", 0}, 
   {9, "M", 1}, 
   {10, "F",0}}
  *)
```